# How to write Micro-controller port function and port number in C code inside MATLAB function block?

Tags: matlab, code-generation

I am trying to write C code into MATLAB function block and generate code using Embedded coder. My function blocks contain some I/O ports functions (i.e. palreadPad(PORT_G, Led_D13))and port identifier(i.e. PORT_G) for a micro controller. When I tried to generate code, MATLAB is showing error message like "Undefined function or variable 'PORT_G'". I need to generate code with these port function and port number in order to run micro controller. I don't want to define the function here because it is a built in function for micro controller. I don't want to set the variable as well (i.e PORT_G=0). How can I avoid the errors and generate code from Embedded coder?

```
function x = my_funcCall()
  x=palreadPad(PORT_G, Led_D13);
end
```

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6tlU.png)

Answer (score 1):

About the error for your present MATLAB code that is not related with C-coding in MATLAB. You should assign a value of a variable before using it. This is a general rule for C and MATLAB and many other programming languages. Thus you should assign values for `PORT_G` and `Led_D13` before calling `palreadPad`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
now MATLAB is not recognizing  "palreadPad()" function. It is showing "Undefined function or variable 'palreadPad'". How can we solve this issue.

Comment: You can just write this function or link to MATLAB the DLL-file with this function.